# VBA - xlvalidation date issue

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I can't run a data validation macro without issues consistently.
Sometimes I'm able to run it without issues, but once the error occurs I can't get rid of it.

My code goes like:

```
AddStuff = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    AddStuff.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(7, 1)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ 
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=TODAY()-7", Formula2:="=TODAY()"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Date"
    .ErrorMessage = "Input must be date between the last 7 days and today."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

The line where I'm getting the error is:

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ 
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=TODAY()-7", Formula2:="=TODAY()"
```

I have tried also

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ 
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=dateadd("d",-7,date), Formula2:=date
```

And also referring to a cell in excel with the date already there but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me?
Thanks alot!

Comment: Please provide details about the error dialog you are seeing, and it might also help to show an image of the cells involved since dates can be tricky in Excel

Comment: Add “.Delete” right after “With Selection.Validation”

Comment: After adding the .Delete right after "With Selection.Validation" my error seems to have vanished. I'm doing more tests to be sure that this is permanent.

The error I was getting was 


"Run-time error "1004":
Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: It’s because you cannot add a validation in a cell that already contains it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **add** data validation to a cell that already contains it.

You can use `.delete` to delete any present validation, then proceed.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDate, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ 
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=TODAY()-7", Formula2:="=TODAY()"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Date"
    .ErrorMessage = "Input must be date between the last 7 days and today."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

---

<sub><sup>Community Wiki Created as a result of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469623/vba-xlvalidation-date-issue#comment85941886_49469623).</sup></sub>